# C++: Enum: Error: Identifier expected instead of "}"

Tags: c++, makefile, enums, solaris

Building jdk8u from openjdk in solaris 11 x86 platform. Getting Warning: Identifier expected instead of "}" error in Enum. Usually this type of error will be thrown when we have comma at end of the enum. But in this case, there is no extra comma also. Can anyone point out what is the issue?
macro.hpp:

```
#ifndef INCLUDE_JFR
#define INCLUDE_JFR 1
#endif

#if INCLUDE_JFR
#define JFR_ONLY(code) code
#else
#define JFR_ONLY(code)
#endif
```

thread.hpp:

```
 enum SuspendFlags {
    // NOTE: avoid using the sign-bit as cc generates different test code
    //       when the sign-bit is used, and sometimes incorrectly - see CR 6398077

    _external_suspend       = 0x20000000U, // thread is asked to self suspend
    _ext_suspended          = 0x40000000U, // thread has self-suspended
    _deopt_suspend          = 0x10000000U, // thread needs to self suspend for deopt

    _has_async_exception    = 0x00000001U, // there is a pending async exception
    _critical_native_unlock = 0x00000002U, // Must call back to unlock JNI critical lock

    JFR_ONLY(_trace_flag    = 0x00000004U)  // call jfr tracing
  };
```

Error:

```
Compiling /export/home/preethi/openjdk8u/hotspot/src/share/vm/compiler/abstractCompiler.cpp
Compiling /export/home/preethi/openjdk8u/hotspot/src/share/vm/utilities/accessFlags.cpp
Compiling ../generated/adfiles/ad_x86_32.cpp
"/export/home/preethi/openjdk8u/hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/thread.hpp", line 202: Warning: Identifier expected instead of "}".
1 Warning(s) detected.
gmake[6]: *** [/export/home/preethi/openjdk8u/hotspot/make/solaris/makefiles/rules.make:148: accessFlags.o] Error 2
gmake[6]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
"/export/home/preethi/openjdk8u/hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/thread.hpp", line 202: Warning: Identifier expected instead of "}".
1 Warning(s) detected.
gmake[6]: *** [/export/home/preethi/openjdk8u/hotspot/make/solaris/makefiles/rules.make:148: abstractCompiler.o] Error 2
"/export/home/preethi/openjdk8u/hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/thread.hpp", line 202: Warning: Identifier expected instead of "}".
1 Warning(s) detected.
gmake[6]: *** [/export/home/preethi/openjdk8u/hotspot/make/solaris/makefiles/rules.make:148: ad_x86_32.o] Error 2
gmake[5]: *** [/export/home/preethi/openjdk8u/hotspot/make/solaris/makefiles/top.make:112: the_vm] Error 2
gmake[4]: *** [/export/home/preethi/openjdk8u/hotspot/make/solaris/Makefile:226: product] Error 2
gmake[3]: *** [Makefile:231: generic_build2] Error 2
gmake[2]: *** [Makefile:177: product] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** [HotspotWrapper.gmk:45: /export/home/preethi/openjdk8u/build/solaris-x86-normal-server-release/hotspot/_hotspot.timestamp] Error 2
gmake: *** [/export/home/preethi/openjdk8u//make/Main.gmk:110: hotspot-only] Error 2
```

rules.make:

```
%.o: %.cpp
        @echo Compiling $<
        $(QUIETLY) $(REMOVE_TARGET)
        $(QUIETLY) $(if $(findstring $@, $(NONPIC_OBJ_FILES)), \
           $(subst $(VM_PICFLAG), ,$(COMPILE.CXX)) $(DEPFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(COMPILE_DONE), \
           $(COMPILE.CXX) $(DEPFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(COMPILE_DONE))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: JFR_ONLY is undefined so the enum ends up with a ','

Answer (score 0):

I think the idea of having an enum element conditional to a definition is not easy to mantain.

If you can't get rid of the Macro you can try this (thanks @Mestkon):

```
#define COMMA ,
enum SuspendFlags {
    // NOTE: avoid using the sign-bit as cc generates different test code
    //       when the sign-bit is used, and sometimes incorrectly - see CR 6398077

    _external_suspend       = 0x20000000U, // thread is asked to self suspend
    _ext_suspended          = 0x40000000U, // thread has self-suspended
    _deopt_suspend          = 0x10000000U, // thread needs to self suspend for deopt

    _has_async_exception    = 0x00000001U, // there is a pending async exception
    _critical_native_unlock = 0x00000002U // (Removed end comma) Must call back to unlock JNI critical lock

    JFR_ONLY(COMMA _trace_flag    = 0x00000004U)  // call jfr tracing

    };
```

Comment: JFR_ONLY(,_trace_flag    = 0x00000004U):  Too many arguments in macro JFR_ONLY error. And JFR_ONLY is defined in the macro.hpp.

Comment: `#define COMMA , ` and `JFR_ONLY(COMMA   _trace_flag = ....)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. The problem i faced was when building jdk8u from openjdk.In configure, i given --enable-jfr=yes, resolved my issue.